# Object size of base class while referring to derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, size, sizeof

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class abc {
  public:
    int a = 45;
  void sum() {
    int s = 55;
    cout << s + a << endl;
  }
};
class xyz: public abc {
  public: int b = 45;
  int c = 54;
  int d = 96;
  int x = 8;
  void show() {
    cout << "xyz class" << endl;
  }
};
int main() {
  abc * ob;
  xyz d;
  ob = & d;
  cout << sizeof( * ob) << endl;
}
```

Why does `sizeof` function return 4 in this case?
From where I stand, the pointer `ob` is pointing to an already created object `d` of derived class `xyz` whose size is 20. So `sizeof(*ob)` should also return this value: 20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator deals with static types, not dynamic ones. `*ob` is of static type `abc`, so that's the size it returns.

Note that `sizeof` is performed at compile time, and there is no way that the compiler could figure out the dynamic type of an instance that is part of an inheritance hierarchy. In your snippet, it looks like this kind of lookup could be easily performed, but imagine

```
abc *ob;

sizeof(*ob);
```

anywhere in some other translation unit, where `xyz` is not even known.

Comment: do you mean `abc* ob;` ?

Comment: A dynamic `sizeof` probably could've been implemented, if the standard required it. E.g. we could store it in `std::type_info`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat how to implement it can you explain?

Comment: @user55092 The implementation I imagined requires modifying the compiler. You can't do it from the program itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is what is written [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof):

> When applied to an expression, sizeof does not evaluate the expression, and even if the expression designates a polymorphic object, the result is the size of the static type of the expression.